# Mule: Setting a property on a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, mule

I'm using Mule v3.5.0

At the moment I have a bean called flowContextEnricher, that sets an object to an eventContext session that contains some information about the flow. This information is later used for the audit logging:

```
@Component
public abstract class AbstractContextEnricher implements Callable {

public Stream buildStream() {
    final Stream stream = ...
    return stream;
}

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

    final Stream stream = buildStream();

    eventContext.getSession().setProperty("stream", stream);

    return eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString();
}
```

I want to reuse this ContextEnricher for both online services and mock services, but for the mock services, an additional boolean propery mock has to be set to 'TRUE'.

I can do this, by adding a separate enricher: MockContectEnricher:

```
@Component
public class MockContextEnricher implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        eventContext.getSession().setProperty("mock", Boolean.TRUE);
        return eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString();
    }
}
```

Then I have to call the additional component for all the mock flows. My total flow looks like this:

```
<flow name="xxxFlowMock" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/xxx/mock" responseTimeout="10000" />
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="mockContextEnricher"/>
    </component>
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="xxxContextEnricher"/>
    </component>
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="auditLogger"/>
    </component>
    ...
</flow>
```

This works, but looks a little weird. Isn't it possible to reuse the xxxContextEnricher for both online and mock services and just set a property on the bean?

```
<property name="mock" value="true">
```

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved it by adding a message-properties-transformer component to every mock flow. By default, if it isn't specified, I set it to false, only in the mock flows I set the property to true.

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="session">
        <add-message-property key="mock" value="true"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Still it would be cleaner to set it through the spring-bean object though...

Answer (score 1):

Having another `MockContextEnricher` shouldn't be too bad. Though I think you can make it better if `MockContextEnricher` class will just extend `xxxContextEnricher`. In this way, you can have like this.

```
@Component
public class MockContextEnricher extends xxxContextEnricher {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        eventContext.getSession().setProperty("mock", Boolean.TRUE);
        return super.onCall(eventContext);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to really remove `MockContextEnricher`. Try this.

Add field (perhaps boolean type) to your `xxxContextEnricher` class for 'mock' property, add use it to conditionally add the 'mock' session property.

Example initialization:

```
<spring:bean id="mockContextEnricher" name="mockContextEnricher" class="com.example.xxxContextEnricher">
   <spring:property name="mock" value="true"/>
</spring:bean>
...
<flow name="xxxFlowMock" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/xxx/mock" responseTimeout="10000" />
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="mockContextEnricher"/>
    </component>
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="auditLogger"/>
    </component>
    ...
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The idea of the MockContextEnricher is nice, but I have a ContextEnricher class for every possible flow (which are +50). This would imply that I have to add 50 new classes that extend the existing ContextEnrichers (I then have flowXContextEnricher & mockFlowXContextEnricher), so in my case there might be a better solution. Conditionally setting the 'mock' session property as a boolean is what I want, but I don't know how the pass it in my current config...